# How does Google Analytics authenticate a website?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Just looking for some general information on how the Google Analytics javascript code placed on the bottom of each page authenicates a website.

Obviously there is a tracking code which is paired to the domain name but is there more to it than that? Is it checking anything else to make sure its secure and not open to misuse?

Comment: Don't understand the question, I think you already answered...the tracking code is an id that matches with your google analytics account. The js script in your page checks that the site is in it's really the website you are running the stats.

Besides, I don't see the point of having a stats script in a different site that the one you added in your google analytics account. In the worst case scenario it would give you wrong figures but it's not a security issue.

Comment: I guess that's his question, can somebody mess up my figures by seeding bad tracking IDs all over the place? Or is Google doing anything to prevent that, like checking referer [sic], or something (not necessarily fool proof)?

Comment: @roe: that is correct. What if someone could manipulate the page headers or something like that?

Comment: hmmm, maybe I didn't think about how this would work properly. The domain name wouldn't be sent from the client-side as it could easily be manipulated in the script. So Google must confirm the domain when the UA-number and whatever other information is sent back via the header info. Now with php I can make that header info whatever I want... so what then?

Comment: @tricat: so what if I had several websites artificially inflating the stat results of another website? Web stats are important to people like in sales trying to sell online advertising or whatever. If that where true everyone would be doing it and nobody would trust Google Analytic stats anymore!

Comment: You could create a robot site that simulates visits to your page anyway. There is no way to know how many visits to your site are real without cleaning up the data that comes up. Besides... who said that Google Analytics can be trusted? ;)

Comment: I think this question should be removed as there is no question as such in the end!

Comment: yes you can, and @Thinker did answer it so I'm happy either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can cheat on it, because domain name read in JS cannot be changed. 
And you didn't mention, that each analytics code has a unique UA-number, which is connected with your domain in google database.

Comment: so sorry, I'm having really bad day :) I was totally thinking server-side and that the ga.js was hosted on the client-side. Duh! Yes I totally understand whats going on now.